# converting Comparable from and to Comparator?

Tags: java

I often have a `Comparator` type while I need a `Comparable` and the other way around. Is there a reusable JDK API to convert from one another? Something along the lines of:

```
    public static <C> Comparable<C> toComparable(final Comparator<C> comparator) {
        // does not compile because Hidden can not extend C, 
        // but just to illustrate the idea
        final class Hidden extends C implements Comparable<C> {
            @Override
            public int compareTo(C another) {
                return comparator.compare((C) this, another);
            }
        };
        return new Hidden();
    }

    public static <C extends Comparable<C>> Comparator<C> toComparator(final Class<C> comparableClass) {
        return new Comparator<C>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(C first, C second) {
                assert comparableClass.equals(first.getClass());
                assert comparableClass.equals(second.getClass());
                return first.compareTo(second);
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ComparableComparator`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparableComparator.html) from Apache Commons Collections seems to address `Comparable<T>` to `Comparator` problem (unfortunately its not generic type-friendly).

The reverse operation is not quite possible because the `Comparator<T>` represents algorithm while `Comparable<T>` represents actual data. You will need composition of some sort. Quick and dirty solution:

```
class ComparableFromComparator<T> implements Comparable<T> {

    private final Comparator<T> comparator;
    private final T instance;

    public ComparableFromComparator(Comparator<T> comparator, T instance) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return comparator.compare(instance, o);
    }

    public T getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Say you have class `Foo` that is not `Comparable<Foo>` but you have `Comparator<Foo>`. You use it like this:

```
Comparable<Foo> comparable = new ComparableFromComparator<Foo>(foo, comparator);
```

As you can see (especially without mixins) it's pretty ugly (and I'm not even sure if it'll work...) Also notice that `comparable` doesn't extend `Foo`, you have to call `.getInstance()` instead.

Comment: For a generics-friendly implementation, Guava's [`Ordering.natural()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#natural()) works, and has lots of extra features.

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain an instance of Comparator able to compare instance of Comparable type simply with

```
java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder()
```

see [Comparator.naturalOrder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--)

this is a sort of conversion from Comparable to Comparator

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 8 the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface has had a few utility default methods added that assist with deriving a comparator from a comparable.

Consider the following example of sorting users by first name.

```
class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}

List<Person> people = ...
people.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::firstName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparable items can be sorted as they have a `compareTo`:

```
Collection<Comparable> items;
Collections.sort(items);
```

If items are *not* Comparable, they need a Comparator object to do the comparison:

```
Collections<T> items;
Collections.sort(items, comparator);
```

A bridging Comparator is trivial, and you did it already.

Wrapping every `T item` with some Comparable adapter having a Comparator, seems useless.
First of all not inheritance but as field one needs to wrap the item.

```
public class CatorComparable<T> implements Comparable<CatorComparable<T>> {
    public T value;
    private Comparator<T> cator;

    public CatorComparable(T value, Comparator<T> cator) {
        this.value = value;
        this.cator = cator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CatorComparable<T> other) {
        return cator.compareTo(value, other.value);
    }
}
```

Too much overhead.

Comment: you are right for most of the Java JDK but there are proprietary libraries that require one or another and then developers wind up programming the conversion boilerplate code all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really convert between them, nor does it really make sense to, since `Comarable` is a property of the class itself, while `Comparator` is an external class.

The best bet would be to write some sort of utility class that contains the underlying comparison logic (and probably have that implement `Comparator`), then use that class as a part of the logic for the `Comparable` implementation on the class itself.

Comment: not true, the `toComparator` works, it is the other `toComparable` the tricky one.